# Conflicting attributes on NSMutableAttributedString: .foregroundColor vs .strokeWidth

Tags: uikit, uitextfield, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I have created a `var` with default text attributes for an `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```swift
static var textFieldDefaultTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
  .font: UIFont(name: "Impact", size: 32)!,
  .tracking: 2,
  .paragraphStyle: getParagraphStyle(),
  .strokeColor: UIColor.black,
  .strokeWidth: 3,
  .foregroundColor: UIColor.white
]
```

When assigning those default styles, the correct color and width are shown for the stroke but **no foreground color is applied** (as shown in the first image below).

However, if I comment out the line that sets the `.strokeWidth` key, the corresponding white foreground color does get rendered but **no stroke is shown** (as seen in the second image below).

I'm relatively new to iOS development so I'm having a hard time tracking down the source of the problem.

[image: Code snippet with Simulator running a Swift app]

[image: Code snippet with Simulator running a Swift app]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1533909-strokewidth),

> Specify positive values to change the stroke width alone. Specify **negative values** to stroke and fill the text.

Just use a negative number for `.strokeWidth`, so both the foreground color and the stroke are rendered.